# How to add common button to all tabs of Tab Host in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am using this code .

```
private ViewGroup createTabbarView() {

        bookedZone = "None";
        bookedStand = "None";

        tabHost = new TabHost(this, null);
        tabHost.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Emergency");
        tabHost.addView(btn, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tabWidget = new TabWidget(this);
        tabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
        tabHost.addView(tabWidget, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        frameLayout.setPadding(0, 100, 0, 0);
        tabHost.addView(frameLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); // WRAP_CONTENT

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            public void onTabChanged(final String tabId) {
                if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("TripList")
                        && (AVL_Service.pref.getBoolean("BluetoothMeter", false) || AVL_Service.pref.getBoolean("VivotechDevice", false) || AVL_Service.pref.getBoolean(
                                "BlueBambooDevice", false))) {
                    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)
                        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    final Context tempContext = getBaseContext();
                    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                        // Device does not support Bluetooth
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Bluetooth not supported.");
                        Toast.makeText(tempContext, "Bluetooth not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Bluetooth not enabled.");
                            Toast.makeText(tempContext, "Bluetooth not enabled, trying to enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                            // tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(ZoneIndex).requestFocusFromTouch();
                        } else {

                            Message lmsg = new Message();
                            lmsg.obj = null;
                            lmsg.what = MsgType.TabberClick;
                            msgHandler.sendMessageDelayed(lmsg, 1000);

                        }// if bluetooth enabled
                    }// if bluetooth not supported
                }// if Bluetooth connection required
                else if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("Status")) {
                    setMeterStatus();
                }
            }// onTabChanged
        });

        tabHost.setup();

        // Status Tab
        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Status");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Status", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.status));
        tabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String arg0) {

                return createStatusView();
            }
        });
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        // Zones Tab
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Zones");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Zones", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.zones));
        tabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String arg0) {

                return createZoneView();
            }
        });
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        // Bids Tab
        bidTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Bids");
        bidTab.setIndicator("Bids", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon + bidCount));
        bidTab.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String arg0) {

                return createBidsView();
            }
        });
        tabHost.addTab(bidTab);

        // TripList Tab
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("TripList");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("TripList", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.triplist));
        tabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String arg0) {

                return createManifestView();
            }
        });
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        return tabHost;
    }
```

// Tabber View

But this button hides the tabs of Tabber view. I want to add to add this button above tabber view. Plz help me..I am in great trouble.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want a button (or buttons) that is above the `TabWidget` tabs regardless of which tab is selected?

Just change your layout file to something similar to this (pseudo-code)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ... >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            ... >
            <Button
                ... />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            ... />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            ... >
            ...
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost
```

Comment: I have tried this but didn't work dynamically. Can u plz tell me how to do it dynamically as I am not using xml.Regards

Comment: Why aren't you using XML? Even if you need to create your tabspec content dynamically there's no reason why you can't use an XML template for the main view and then simply generate the tabspec content. It seems to me you're making a lot of work for yourself